# 'publishing to glassfish 4.0 at localhost...' has encountered a prblem. cannot deploy SocialNetwork

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee

cannot Deploy SocialNetwork

deploy is failing=Error occurred during deployment:

Exception while deploying the app [SocialNetwork] :

Servlet [Update_ansServ] and Servlet [SocialNetwork.servlet.Update_ansServ]

have the same url pattern: [/Update_ansServ].

Related annotation information:

```
annotation [@javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet(loadOnStartup=-1, 
    initParams=[], urlPatterns=[], displayName=, name=, largeIcon=, 
    description=, asyncSupported=false, smallIcon=, value=[/Update_ansServ])]
```

on annotated element [class SocialNetwork.servlet.Update_ansServ] of type [TYPE].

Please see server.log for more details.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please edit your question and add things like spaces and line breaks so we can tell what you're actually asking? it's all just one bg wall of text - which is really hard to read.

Comment: i added some quick-and-dirty spaces so we can read it a bit better... but you need to add more than just the error-log. Can you show us the relevant sections of code and also what it is you are trying to do?

Comment: i have just added my project in glassfish server and when am publishing this error comes up ...

Comment: package SocialNetwork.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import SocialNetwork.bean.*;
import SocialNetwork.util.DataConnection;

Comment: @WebServlet("/Update_ansServ")
@MultipartConfig(location="",fileSizeThreshold=1024*1024*5,maxFileSize=1024*1024*10,maxRequestSize=1024*1024*50)
public class Update_ansServ extends HttpServlet {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  response.setContentType("text/html");
  PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();

Comment: DataConnection d=new DataConnection();
  try {
   d.getConnection();
   Questions e = new Questions();
   e.setQu_id(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("qu_id")));
   e.setAnswer(request.getParameter("answer"));
   e.setAdate(request.getParameter("adate"));
  
   if(d.updateans(e)){
    request.getRequestDispatcher("Q&A_teacher.jsp").include(request, response);
    out.println("<div class='footer'><p>Item Updated Successfully</p><!-- end .footer --></div>");
   }

Comment: else{
    request.getRequestDispatcher("Q&A_teacher.jsp").include(request, response);
    out.println("<div class='footer'><p>Error Occured!!!!</p><!-- end .footer --></div>");
   }
  } catch (SQLException e1) {
   e1.printStackTrace();
  }
  d.closeAll();
 }

}

Comment: @TarynEast  maam i have just posted my code in 4 segments.. plz help me to debug my error.. thank you in advnce :)

Comment: argh... noo... formatting of code in comments is awful (as you can see). Instead please edit your question and ad the code there (it is part of your original question, not a comment about it)